# I want to do some work whenever user enter any text in data gridview cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` which displays product details.
I want to update my product name whenever user enter product code.
Is there any method like `datagridview_TextChanged`?

Comment: What are you developing? Winforms? ...

Comment: @chiapa, `datagridview` is Winforms control. @Linojan, show what did you tried already? Try to play with handlers of `datagridview.CellBeginEdit` and `datagridview.CellEndEdit` events

Comment: @Fabio thnx alot. datagridview.CellEndEdit is right solution for my problem!!!

Comment: Good that you find solution by yourself :)